# Void Method to Reverse Own Implementation of Java LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list

Whatever way it's possible, how can I do this? I need a method that modifies the actual list itself. I have tried doing this:

```java
// Reverses this list.
public void reverse() {
    for (int i = 0, j = size - 1; i < size && j >= 0; i++, j--)
        set(i, get(j));
}
```

... but I failed. Halfway through it starts over and I'm just sucking. The output ends up being:

```
List:       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
Reversed:   [24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
```

How can I avoid this problem of repeating the numbers once it reaches the middle? Thanks.

Comment: Please don't tell us what you want. Tell us what you've tried and why it hasn't worked.

Comment: Ok, delete my comment but don't notice *that I have added the code.*

Comment: @GabrielRyanNahmias, now it's better than earlier. But once you ask specific question, I will vote for re-open :)

Comment: Take it easy. First try debugging, then take a look at the implementation of `Collections.reverse(List)`.

Comment: I'm sorry; I have an infected face and I'm not in a good mood. How's this now?

Comment: Setting isn't enough, you need to swap elements.

Comment: Ok. Do you have any examples you might provide to demonstrate this tactic?

Comment: @GabrielRyanNahmias just as Sotirios Delimanolis has mentioned use Collections.reverse(list) method. Collections is part of java.utils.

Comment: Here's some old source code: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.reverse%28java.util.List%29

Comment: This isn't helping. I am implementing my own `List` interface so I have no iterators for this specific class. Is there no other way??

Comment: The point is you have to take an element at one index and swap it with an element at another index. I don't know how your `set` method is implemented but it doesn't seem like that's what it's doing. You only need one index that goes from 0 until size/2.

Comment: I'm still just lapsing to understand exactly what I'm doing wrong so if you can demonstrate anything, that'd be pimp. I'll look at my `set()` method, too, thanks.

Comment: i tried doing this, using removelast method of the linkedlist but noticed that only the first 12 elements are read. :O..and they are reversed well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you go through the list, you are overwriting the first half of the values with values from the end, thereby losing those early values. When you get to the second half of the list, the original values in the first half are no longer there!

Try using swap logic (exchanging two elements at each iteration) and going only halfway through the list:

```
public void reverse() {
    int half = size / 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < half; i++) {
        int j = size - 1 - i; // position of matching element at the other end
        T item = get(i); // T is the type of data stored in the list
        set(i, get(j));
        set(j, item);
    }
}
```

Note that you don't need to swap the middle element with itself.

Comment: Very thorough and I appreciate this.

Answer (score 1):

Sir,

I managed to do this, you could may be add your own logic to reduce the for loops that i have used. But i hope it helps in a way.

```
    for(int i=0;i<list.size()/2;i++) {
        int val = list.removeLast();
        System.out.println("i:" + i + " val " + val);
        reverseList.add(val);
    }

    for(int i=list.size()/2;i<list.size();i++) {
        int val = list.removeLast();
        System.out.println("i:" + i + " val " + val);
        reverseList.add(val);
    }

    for(int i=list.size()/4;i<list.size();i++) {
        int val = list.removeLast();
        System.out.println("i:" + i + " val " + val);
        reverseList.add(val);
    }

    for(int i=list.size()/6;i<list.size();i++) {
        int val = list.removeLast();
        System.out.println("i:" + i + " val " + val);
        reverseList.add(val);
    }

    for(int i=list.size()/8;i<list.size();i++) {
        int val = list.removeLast();
        System.out.println("i:" + i + " val " + val);
        reverseList.add(val);
    }

    for(int i=list.size()/10;i<list.size();i++) {
        int val = list.removeLast();
        System.out.println("i:" + i + " val " + val);
        reverseList.add(val);
    }

    for(int i=list.size()/12;i<list.size();i++) {
        int val = list.removeLast();
        System.out.println("i:" + i + " val " + val);
        reverseList.add(val);
    }
```

Comment: Neat, although I think I prefer the alternative.

Comment: But i still dont understand why this happens so in a linked list :(